# Google Distance Matrix API for two-wheel

Tags: google-distancematrix-api

I am trying to get the time it takes to get from place A to place B, using several mode of transportation: four-wheel, two-wheel, bicycle, and walk. I am stumbled upon the google distance matrix API and I think it solve my problem, but it's missing the two-wheeler option. Does anybody know how to get the information for the two wheel? or if you have other alternatives I would kindly appreciate it.

P.S. I assume the `driving` mode they mention in the reference API docs (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/distance-matrix) is used for four wheeler

Answer (score 0):

### Use Routes API instead of Distance Matrix API

According to the documentation you provided, specifically at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/distance-matrix#mode, a two-wheeled vehicle type is not available for computing travel time between locations for Distance Matrix API.

However, the **Routes API** allows computing directions between two locations using the `computeRoutes` method and supports the **two-wheeled vehicle type**. Reference: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/routes/route_two_wheel#specify_the_two-wheeler_travel_mode.

Please note though that two-wheeled vehicle type is currently available to limited countries and regions. You can view the list of the supported countries and regions here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/routes/coverage-two-wheeled.

Here's a sample Routes API request that returns the *duration, distance, and polyline direction* between two locations in India using the `"travelMode":"TWO_WHEELER"`:

```
curl -X POST -d '{
  "origin":{
    "address": "H8MW+WP Kolkata India"
  },
  "destination":{
    "address": "GCG2+3M Kolkata India"
  },
  "travelMode":"TWO_WHEELER"
}' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'X-Goog-Api-Key: YOUR_API_KEY' \
-H 'X-Goog-FieldMask: routes.duration,routes.distanceMeters,routes.polyline.encodedPolyline' \
'https://routes.googleapis.com/directions/v2:computeRoutes'
```

Which returns the following response:

```
{
  "routes": [
    {
      "distanceMeters": 14255,
      "duration": "2563s",
      "polyline": {
        "encodedPolyline": "adzhCcgfzOiA|H]rC?pAb@d@N@jBC`@DTNPb@BVGp@i@tAOfA]hBW`@c@xBeE_AeA_@TuALgALoB\\wBRo@x@kBJY`EsXj@eDPS`@S`@E^@r@PRFhGF`@DjBn@T@ZILKLUzBiGj@wAb@mAJQt@i@d@WrAc@n@GrAGnAI|@A|AT`Dr@nG|AdB\\`@@tBf@`@j@HFhBh@|@Lx@Kv@LjHlBtAXrM`DxCx@pIpBhCn@xChAv@XbAH|A\\|a@tKhHjBrATJYBORe@FcAPkLFoCAcCEy@Q_A@q@Fk@He@l@gA\\c@~A}Ad@]lImI`CmB`JcHxCkJzB_Id@w@X_@`BwA`A_A`@s@|@eClAcEr@sAfCkD|HwLpAmBTWDe@KYCYDYTa@\\WXCR?p@{@NKn@w@p@k@l@_@hDqAf@a@Za@Xu@j@aCr@{B^qAZD^iAAWlB{JLuAZ_I@cBi@mGJiD?_BCy@QoBc@yBcBgFsAgD{AkEgCgIa@iBWuBI_B@uBJqAPcARgCDsBGyBKkA[aCs@oEm@aEs@qGYsAUcAw@iEg@yDEcABoB^sDRm@j@oAIUBSNQPCRFHLhDh@`SrC~@HxDn@rThDpK|AhG~@fHpAdBRhBJvCIv@K~Ag@dDwAQy@H}@n@gE`@_EFOfAsIH{@@m@Lc@VwAUMgBq@"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```